# Clicking on a submit button does not hit the server side code in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-core, http, razor-pages

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor Pages project. I have a form that has a submit button but when I click on it execution is not hitting the Post handler in the page model. I'm using WebAPI as well in the same Razor Pages project

my startup class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages()
        .AddNewtonsoftJson()
        .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
    
    services.AddControllers()
        .AddNewtonsoftJson()
    .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        //app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        //app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
    
}
```

my .cshtml:

```
@page
@model CandidateBowl.WebPortal.Pages.JobAdvertisement.AddModel
@{
}

<form method="post" action="/Handlers?handler=Advertisement">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row p-5 border pt-4 my-3 rounded">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="JobAdvertisementModel.CompanyId" />
            <div class="col-12 px-3 mb-3 border-bottom text-center text-uppercase">
                <h2 class="text-primary">Job Advertisement</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="col-9 pt-3">
                <div class="input-group row mb-3">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 d-sm-block">
                        <label asp-for="JobAdvertisementModel.IndustryId"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                        <select class="form-select" asp-for="JobAdvertisementModel.IndustryId" asp-items="Model.Options">
                            <option value=""></option>
                        </select>
                        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="JobAdvertisementModel.IndustryId"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group row mb-3">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 d-sm-block">
                        <label asp-for="JobAdvertisementModel.Title"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                        <input class="form-control" asp-for="JobAdvertisementModel.Title" />
                        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="JobAdvertisementModel.Title"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group row mb-3">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 d-sm-block">
                        <label asp-for="JobAdvertisementModel.Salary"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                        @* use year selector *@
                        <input class="form-control" asp-for="JobAdvertisementModel.Salary" />
                        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="JobAdvertisementModel.Salary"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group row mb-3">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 d-sm-block">
                        <label asp-for="JobAdvertisementModel.Location"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                        @* use year selector *@
                        <input class="form-control" asp-for="JobAdvertisementModel.Location" />
                        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="JobAdvertisementModel.Location"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group row mb-3">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 d-sm-block">
                        <label asp-for="JobAdvertisementModel.Role"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                        @* use year selector *@
                        <input class="form-control" asp-for="JobAdvertisementModel.Role" />
                        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="JobAdvertisementModel.Role"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="input-group row mb-3">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 d-sm-block">
                        <label asp-for="JobAdvertisementModel.Requirements"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                        @* use year selector *@
                        <textarea class="form-control" asp-for="JobAdvertisementModel.Requirements"></textarea>
                        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="JobAdvertisementModel.Requirements"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="input-group row mb-3">
                    <div class="col-md-9 offset-3 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary form-control">Save</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                                @* return to candidate details page *@
                                <a asp-page="Index" class="btn btn-success form-control">Back To Job Advertisements </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/js/tinMCE.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

my code behind

```
public class AddModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IJobAdvertisementRepository jobAdvertisementRepository;
        private readonly IIndustryRepository industryRepository;

        public AddModel(IJobAdvertisementRepository jobAdvertisementRepository, IIndustryRepository industryRepository)
        {
            this.jobAdvertisementRepository = jobAdvertisementRepository;
            this.industryRepository = industryRepository;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public JobAdvertisementModel JobAdvertisementModel { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> Options { get; set; }
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
        {
            Options = industryRepository.GetIndustries().Result.Select(a => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = a.Id.ToString(),
                Text = a.Name
            }).ToList();

            return Page();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAdvertisementAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Options = industryRepository.GetIndustries().Result.Select(a => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = a.Id.ToString(),
                    Text = a.Name
                }).ToList();

                return Page();
            }

            var id = await jobAdvertisementRepository.AddAdvertisement(JobAdvertisementModel);

            if (id == 0)
                return Page();

            return RedirectToPage();//still to decide where it should go
        }
    }
```

What could the issue be?

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
<form method="post" action="/Handlers?handler=Advertisement">
```

to

```
<form method="post" asp-page-handler="Advertisement">
```

This will generate the following HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="/Add?handler=Advertisement">
```

And like @PritomSarkar says, fix your button

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You posted that you have a form that has a submit button. I guess you mean this line `<button class="btn btn-primary form-control">Save</button>` is not working.

If that's the case, try this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary form-control"/>
```

Also make sure that `action="/Handlers?handler=Advertisement"` is correct in your form.